# Angular directive inserts wrong DOM node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an app with many forms. Each field has several HTML elements, so I thought I could extract some directives (one per type of field) to keep my forms tidy.

I've created a [sample app](http://plnkr.co/edit/YXAjp2jDuuKfDrpbOkZV?p=preview) to demonstrate the problem, but I'm getting inconsistent behavior. In the sample app, a `<link />` element replaces the `<input />`. In my real app, `<input />` just gets removed from the DOM completely. I feel like this should be easy; why doesn't it work?

Comment: it seems like your `ng-transclude` is in the wrong place.  ng-transclude is a Directive that marks the insertion point for the transcluded DOM of the nearest parent directive that uses transclusion.

Any existing content of the element that this directive is placed on will be removed before the transcluded content is inserted.  Seems as though your form element contents would be replaced. (If your sample were functional).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your stated question, it's because you told it to, with `ng-transclude`.  That replaces the contents of the tag with the original element, which I don't think you wanted; you probably wanted the original contents to be transcluded as the label instead.

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
<div class="form-group" >
  <label for="{{htmlId}}" ng-transclude></label>
  <input id="{{htmlId}}" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="model" />
  <span ng-repeat="error in errors">{{error}}</span>
</div>
```

I've moved the tranclusion into the label.  While this works, I would also recommend the style of actually passing a `label` attribute, rather than transclude it, just for the sake of having a consistent API and simpler code; it's functionally equivalent, though, so don't let me bully you.

Also, you've got a few errors in your .js as well.  First, you want to use `=` in your scope instead of `&`

```
scope: {
  model: '=',
  errors: '='
},
```

`&` is used to pass methods, while `=` is used for objects (*this is a simplification*).  Since your `model` and `errors` are objects, you'll want to use `=` instead.

Finally, in your example, your html template and your directive's template don't have the same name... you've got an extra 's' in your .js, but that's probably just in the plunker and not your real app.

Comment: Thanks. I got this one working. Can you elaborate on "`&` for methods, `=` for objects"? I understand you are simplifying, and I've used them both before, but it sounds like you have a better understanding than I do.

Comment: [Angular Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile#description_comprehensive-directive-api_directive-definition-object).  In short, since you've made an isolated scope that doesn't automatically inherit from the parent, you have to connect manually.  `=` sets up a two-way binding between properties (which are usually objects) so when one is updated the other is too, and is the most common assignment.  `&` gives you a reference to call a function as if you were parent scope, and mostly used if you could be used by multiple controllers and need to call a different method depending on which